# Using sort with space as a field separator

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm trying to use the `sort` command to sort integers in string separated by a space. For example `8 6 5 7 9 56 -20 - 10`. I receive the string on the standard output. I tried all of these but nothing works :

```
sort -t' '
sort -t ' '
sort -t " "
sort -t" "
sort -t=" "
```

Comment: From `man sort`: "sort **lines** of text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "8 6 5 7 9 56 -20 - 10" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n
```

Sort can only sort lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can first read string into an array with space as delimiter then use `sort` with process substitution:

```
s='8 6 5 7 9 56 -20 - 10'
read -ra arr <<< "$s"
sort -n <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
```

**Output:**

```
-20
-10
5
6
7
8
9
56
```

To store output in string again:

```
read -r str < <(sort -n <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}") | tr '\n' ' ')
```

And check output:

```
declare -p str
declare -- str="-20 -10 5 6 7 8 9 56"
```